# vb.net get cell value from word file table

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, cell

I have some code to get cell value from a word file table.

But it contains something like 口 and will generate a line which is useless, how can I remove this character?

```
Dim num As String = Trim$(wordApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(6,1).Range.Text)
    MsgBox(num)
```

[output is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvvKK.png)

But I'm sure the original cell value doesn't have a empty line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example (with VBA):

```
String = Split(wordApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(6,1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
```

The ¤ is Word's end-of-cell marker, which you need to exclude.